# Explaination of high current zener transistor regulator circuit

Tags: transistors, capacitor, voltage-regulator, zener, high-current

This is a high current zener TRANSISTOR regulator circuit. I want to know

- What does "high current" mean here?
- How is this circuit working as a zener regulator?
- What is the purpose of transistor here?How is it working?
- What is the main component in the circuit diagram?
- What is the purpose of capacitor here?
- Why is the purpose of resistor here?

  [image]

Comment: If this is homework, it is good practise to show some effort of how far you get on your own. The other users on EE.SE can then elaborate on your thoughts where necessary.

Comment: No I found this as an example circuit of zener regulator on line but did not understand how does this circuit work?

Comment: You said it was high current in the title so you please justify that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't know what to [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=transistor+and+zener+diode) for, I'll give you [this](http://www.bristolwatch.com/ele/zener_power_supply.htm) to read for starters.

> What does "high current" mean here?

"high current" means that you can draw the maximum current provided from the input with a proper transistor

> How is this circuit working as a zener regulator?

the transistor can provide constant emitter voltage, because it has constant base (reference) voltage. for more, read the next link.

> What is the purpose of transistor here? How is it working?

Read [this](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_1.html)

> What is the main component in the circuit diagram?

what do you mean by main? they are all required

> What is the purpose of capacitor here?

Usually, the output capacitor is set for high current startup load and for further voltage smoothing

> Why is the purpose of resistor here?

Read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/81429/61613) and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/142003/61613)

Comment: Eh, ""high current" means that you can draw the maximum current provided from the input with a proper transistor". Zener diodes usually don't scale up in terms of current well. You can find high-current transistors much easier/cheaper. Also this is a series regulator and a single Zener would have to be a shunt.

Comment: Also, I realize this is an old question, but the purpose of the transistor in this circuit can be explained in a sentence or two. The external link you provided for that particular question doesn't directly answer it, and in any case it's a good idea to make answers as self-contained as reasonably possible (and by that I don't mean including a whole transistor tutorial as in this answer, of course).